# Compile error when trying to mock a generic method with Moq

Tags: unit-testing, c#-3.0, moq

I have a method I'd like to mock:

```
public interface IServiceBus
{
    void Subscribe<T>(ISubscribeTo<T> subscriber) where T : class;
}
```

For the sake of this example, `T` can be something called `SomeType`.
Now, I'd like to mock this, like so:

```
var mockServiceBus = new Mock<IServiceBus>();
mockServiceBus.Setup(x => x.Subscribe(It.IsAny<ISubscribeTo<SomeType>>));
```

However, when I try this, I get this compile error:

> Error 65
>   The type arguments for method 'ServiceBus.IServiceBus.Subscribe(Messaging.ISubscribeTo)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage.
>   Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

I'm not sure how to work around this error. Any ideas? Or is this behavior not possible to mock with Moq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this (adding parentheses since `It.IsAny<TValue>` is a method):

```
mockServiceBus.Setup(x => x.Subscribe(It.IsAny<ISubscribeTo<SomeType>>()));
```

Comment: I feel really, really stupid now that *that* turned out to be the problem. Haha. Oh well, just one of those days. Thank you, that was it!

Comment: It's not that I'm new to Mock, I was just expecting it to be some crazy generics issue that Mock somehow didn't support :-) haha

Comment: No worries, I only knew it because I've done the same thing.  More than once :P